# Renaming CSV column header and merge results with Powershell

Tags: csv, powershell, import, export

So I'm just starting out with this whole Powershell thing and so far so good - until now. I just can't figure out how to do this!
I'm looking at manipulating CSV files which are output from one system (which I can't change at output), renaming some column headers and merging a couple of the results into one column so that it matches the input requirements to upload into another system (again, I can't change those parameters).
So, as an example.

The first file is created:
File1.csv
"A","B","C""1","2","3"

I want a powershell script that will output:
File2.csv
"X","Y""1","23"
So I can import it into another system.

I hope that all makes sense, and thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that your actual/desired formats of your files look like this:

```
"A","B","C"
"1","2","3"
```

```
"X","Y"
"1","23"
```

rather than having everything in one line. If that's correct you can import `File1.csv` with [`Import-Csv`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849891.aspx), rename and merge columns with [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

```
... | Select-Object @{n='X';e={$_.A}}, @{n='Y';e={$_.B + $_.C}} | ...
```

and write the result to `File2.csv` with [`Export-Csv`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx).